# CSS keep footer flag

Tags: css

I have the following issue with the next code posted in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9XVV/1/

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="header">THGE HEADER OF THE PAGE</div>
    <div class="thebody">
        HERE GOES THE CONTENT OF THE PAGE......
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footerContent">
            <div class="footer1">Footer section</div>
            <div class="footer2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#FFFF58;
    }
    .thebody {
        width:500px;
        height:400px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color:#DDD;
    }
    .footer {
        width:500px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#696969;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .footerContent {
        width:500px;
        height:50px;
    }
    .footer1 {
        width:400px;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
    }
    .footer2 {
        width:100px;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#FFddFF;
        position:fixed;
        right:0;
    }
```

The question is that the pink Div should always stay on the footer and fixed on the right, but if window width is less than body width plus pink Div width, the pink Div should be kept on the left of the main footer (500px width)

Another issue is that scrolling the content, the pink div should always stay at the same level of the footer.

Comment: And where's the question?

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
.footer2 {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#FFddFF;
}
@media all and (max-width: 649px){
    .footer2 {
        position: inline;
        float: right
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 650px){
    .footer2 {
        position:fixed;
        right:0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b9XVV/2/

Watch the compatibility of the media queries: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries Your main problem (if applicable) is IE8.

Comment: Mooseman, thanks a lot for your help but i made a mistake and your solution is almost great but instead of on the left of the footer, it's on the right, just aside the footer.  very much sorry for the misunderstood.

Comment: Mooseman, just right the footer, I mean, [.....footer.....][..pink div..], and what about in case the body content is high enough a user need to scroll. Here the issue is that the pink div always remain at the bottom of the screen and not the footer as it should be.

Comment: Here I have a small solution based on your last one. http://jsfiddle.net/b9XVV/4/ Only remains the fact that when width content is higher than 650px, if you resize the window doing it smaller, you will notice that Pink Div always remains at the bottom of the screen. Is there any solution for this remain at the same level of the footer?